# Cant workout how to compare two string decimals in numeric equation

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7.9

I have two strings that I've extracted from AWS Billing reports

e.g. 1.14 and 2.75

I'm parsing a string line by line and dropping these values into a var (they appear in set positions after the word 'Maximum' and before a last comma.

e.g.

```
from decimal import *
for line in output.split('\n'):
        top_answer = 0
        if "Maximum" in line:
                ext = line.strip()[10:-1]
                ans = Decimal(ext)
                print(ext,top_answer)
                if ans > top_answer:
                        top_answer = ans
print(top_answer)
```

The output is:

(' 1.46', 0)
(' 1.37', 0)
(' 1.3', 0)
0

I've tried using floats (that was scary and didn't work), I've tried comparing the strings, but that obviously didn't work. I'm now on decimals, but really struggling. Everything I try returns that ext>top_answer, which it is not.

Any ideas on how to do this, virtually every other language I've used was a lot easier.

BTW im a part time programmer for my home automation delight, so don't give me too hard a time about my programming lazyness :)

Thanks.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting `top_answer` to 0 all the time

```
from decimal import *
for line in output.split('\n'):
        top_answer = 0                  # set to zero on each begin of line
        if "Maximum" in line:
                ext = line.strip()[10:-1]
                ans = Decimal(ext)
                print(ext,top_answer)
                if ans > top_answer:
                    # whatever, top_answer will be replaced by 0 anyway.
```

You should put `top_answer=0` *before* the loop. Your last line in `output` does not contain any "Maximum" - but the top_answer will be reset to 0 non the less - so you only ever get zeros for it.

In python 2.x you do not need parenthesis arount print btw - thats why you get a "tuple" like output

Comment: @GrantCaley: you might want to delete the question or mark it as answered: [how-does-accepting-an-answer-work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)